# Fetch data based on the logged in user information from two different tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a log-in form where the user input his username and password. Every user has his gradelevel assign and section.

My main concern is my code cannot determine whose user is currently logged in so it cannot get the gradeassign and sectionassign of it so all of data from the tbl_students are displayed.

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Here's the table structure

tbl_user

```
| id | Name | gradeassign | sectionassign | Username | Password     
----------------------------------            
|  1 | XXXX |     2       |       3       |    xxx   |  xxx      
|  2 | YYYY |     1       |       2       |          |   
|  3 | ZZZZ |     1       |       6       |          |
```

tbl_students

```
| id | Name  | Grade      | Section   
----------------------------------            
|  1 | George|     2      |   3            
|  2 | YYYY  |     1      |   2              
|  3 | ZZZZ  |     1      |   1
```

If the user XXX log-in, the result and date fetched must be:

```
| id | Name  | Grade | Section |     
----------------------------------            
|  1 | George |   2   |   3     |
```

Here's my code for the log-in session of the user.

```
 <?php 
require_once('connection.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
   if(empty($_POST['Username']) || empty($_POST['Password']))
   {
        header("location:faculty.php?Empty=All fields are required");
   }
   else
   {
          $query="select * from facultyagain where Username='".$_POST['Username']."'
```

and Pass='".$_POST['Password']."'";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

```
        if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $_SESSION['User']=$_POST['Username'];
            header("location:faculty2.php");
        }
        else
        {
            header("location:faculty.php?Invalid= Unauthorized Access ");
        }
   }
}
else
{
    echo 'Not Working Now Guys';
}

?>
```

--------Here's the query I've tried to fetch my desired result.

```
 <?php

   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");  

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students INNER JOIN tbl_user WHERE 
  tbl_user.gradeassign = 
  tbl_students.grade AND tbl_user.sectionassign = tbl_students.section";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

 ?>  

      <?php  
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                      {  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["grade"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["section"]; ?></td> 

                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                           }  
                      }

                      ?>
```

Comment: _My main concern is my code cannot determine whose user is..._ and my main concern is about the high vulnerability of your query for sql injection..fix this first

Comment: What is the realtion between XXX and George?

Comment: George will be displayed since its section and grade corresponds with the gradeassign and sectionassign of the user who logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You storing `username` after login. Please store `userId` in session `instead of` username. Then try this query to fetch results.

**WARNING** SQL QUERY IS VULNERABLE FOR SQL-INJECTION

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");  
  $current_user_id = $_SESSION['User'];
  //I recommend you to validate session for empty or non authorized user.

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE tbl_students.id = '$current_user_id' INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.id = tbl_students.id";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

 ?>  

      <?php  
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                      {  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["grade"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["section"]; ?></td> 

                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                           }  
                      }

                      ?>
```

Comment: All data which grade and section corresponds with the user gradeassign and sectionassign will be fetch, regardless of ID. How can I achieve that?

Comment: $current_user_id = $_SESSION['User'];
And wait, where does "USER" came from? Please enlighten me sir. Thankyou so much

Comment: First you should design the db properly, There is `ID` but i really don't know, that is `row_id` or `student_id` or anything else...

Comment: You are already setting the ` $_SESSION['User'];` when user login

Comment: The data will be displayed are all based from the user gradeassign and section assign. How sir?

Comment: Your expecting result is same as table `tbl_students` there is nothing to join, Just filter with ID, or Grade or Section using Where

Comment: Hi! Just wanna clarify something. I tried adding the tbl_students.id = '$current_user_id' on the query but it returns the error   """"mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in""".

Comment: That means, The parameter 1 of fucntion `mysqli_num_rows()` shold be a `mysqli_result` type object. Your given parameter is boolean. thats why.. Put the query relust veriable as input.